# Text not visible in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

My listview isn't showing text from my array, I think the text is transparent somehow but I don't know how to change it so that it just shows up as black text.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);
    ListView levelOneListView = findViewById(R.id.levelOneListView);

    String[] easyList = new String[]{
             "Daisy", "Dandelion", "Grass", "Rock", "Tree", "Postbox"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, easyList);
    levelOneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




}
```

}

I have tried changing the text colour to multiple different colours but none of them are visible in the listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/levelOneListView"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#0A0A0A"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

When I run the emulator it will show the checkboxes but not the actual text

Comment: The `textColor` attribute will have no effect on a `<ListView>`. Please [edit] your question to provide the relevant code, where you set up the `ListView` and its `Adapter`.

Comment: provide some code, how do you populate listview?

Comment: OK, you've set up the `Adapter` correctly, inasmuch as you're using the `Activity` for the `Context`; i.e., the `this` argument. That means that the `ListView` items will follow the theme set on the `Activity`, and the default themes will have contrasting background and text colors. Did you happen to set your own background color on the `<ListView>`'s parent in `activity_level_one`? Or did you possibly fiddle with the colors in the `Activity`'s theme? That is, did you modify any of the colors or attribute values in the `res/` folders?

Comment: I did change it to have no taskbar but changed it back in an attempt to correct the issue

Comment: Did you set a `background` attribute on the `<ListView>`'s parent – i.e., a `<ViewGroup>` that surrounds it – in `activity_level_one`? From your description, it sounds like you've currently got a light background, so what happens if you set `android:background="#000000"` on the `<ListView>`, as a test? Can you see your text then?

Comment: If I set a dark background the text comes up white

Comment: Then, if the code you've shown is exactly as you're running, it sounds like you have a dark (regular) theme set on the `Activity`, and you've changed some background in `activity_level_one` to a light color. A dark theme will have dark backgrounds, and light text colors. Since your text shows up with a light color, the `Activity` apparently has a theme that's set up for dark backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/levelOneListView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

and

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);
    ListView levelOneListView = findViewById(R.id.levelOneListView);

    String[] easyList = new String[]{
             "Daisy", "Dandelion", "Grass", "Rock", "Tree", "Postbox"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, easyList);
    levelOneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    levelOneListView.notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to fix it